# search for a folder buried in a folder and move the folder to a new destination

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7

I want to move the Favorites folder from a folder that changes its folder guid daily from `Appsense`.

Text between quotes changes.

```
C:\appsensevirtual\S-1-5-21-220523388-2000478354-839522115-60875\'{647CFC75-E4C0-4F13-9888-C37BA083416C}'\_Microsoft Office 2010
```

I have found this but it never copies to the H: (Homedrive).

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Appsensevirtual" -Recurse -Filter "Favorites*" -Directory | 
Move-Item -Destination "H:\Favorites"
```

If i run I get this in an Powershell Administrator Window (powershell 2)

```
PS C:\temp> .\favorites.ps1
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Directory'.
At C:\temp\favorites.ps1:1 char:76
+ Get-ChildItem "C:\Appsensevirtual" -Recurse -Filter "Favorites*" -Directory <<<<  | Move-Item -Destination "H:\Favorites"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: Does the Get-ChildItem command return something ? Could we have a real sample, since I don't see Favorties in any path mentioned ?

Comment: So your issue there is the `-Directory` parameter does not exist (did you read the error message ?). To filter only folders in Get-ChildItem, you need to replace -Directory with `| Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer }` (implied `-eq $True`). Test this without the move to see if it finds the required folders.

Comment: Yes but having no powershell experience I am a noobie.

So you want me to run:-

Get-ChildItem "C:\Appsensevirtual" -Recurse -Filter "Favorites*" | | Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer } (implied -eq $True) "H:\Favorites"

Comment: So i have ran the line below and it has returned no info or errors

Get-ChildItem "C:\appsensevirtual" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }

Comment: PS C:\temp> Get-ChildItem "C:\appsensevirtual" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } (implied -eq $True)
The term 'implied' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, veri
fy that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:89
+ Get-ChildItem "C:\appsensevirtual" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } (implied <<<<  -eq $True)
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (implied:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: `PS C:\Users\mm> gci . -rec -filter "Favorites*" | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }` gives me `d-r--        07/12/2013     00:27            Favorites`, so it should be fine. Also `Get-ChildItem "C:\appsensevirtual" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }` should give you all the folders in the path, so you have an issue. Are folders hidden or virtual, so they are not shown using `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem` provider

Comment: I tried this and it returns nothing, although you are right that c:\appsensevirtual is a windows hidden folder 

'PS C:\appsensevirtual> gci . -rec -filter "Favorites*" | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }'

Comment: 'gci . -rec -filter "Favorites*" | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }' returns no data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solution is:
Remove `-Directory` from your command, and add `-Force` which will parse system & hidden folders.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Appsensevirtual" -Recurse -Filter "Favorites*" -Force |
Move-Item -Destination "H:\Favorites"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what error I had

`Move-Item : Source and destination path must have identical roots. Move will not work across volumes.
At line:1 char:84
+ Get-ChildItem "C:\Appsensevirtual" -Recurse -Filter "Favorites*" -Force | Move-Item <<<<  -Destination "H:\Favorites"
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Appsensevirt...raham\Favorites:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand`

Comment: Matt this is now working to my c:\ :)

I was in the c:\appsensevirtual folder, once i ran the command from the c: it worked, I can copy the file from c: to h:.

Massive thank you for your help and patience

Comment: @AdiGraham: Don't forget to mark as answer if it fits. It will help the next ones who get the same issue.

Comment: Hi Matt, just tried this again and not working at all, just goes to the next line, wonder if had already made the folder before - my test machine is a mess!

Comment: @AdiGraham: try adding -force, to handle the case where folder already exist. Tell us if it works

Comment: I already had the -force in as per your instructions earlier ^^ - I have also manually created the directory and deleted and reran it but no errors, just drops to a new line.

`Get-ChildItem "C:\Appsensevirtual" -Recurse -Filter "Favorites*" -Force | Move-Item -Destination "H:\Favorites"`

Comment: @AdiGraham: Add it to the `Move-Item` command :) else try again without the move-item to see which command is noop, the Get-ChildItem or the Move-Item

Comment: Doh!

If i run these nothing happens

`Get-ChildItem "C:\Appsensevirtual" -Recurse -Filter "Favorites*" -Force | Move-Item -force -Destination "C:\OLD_XP_DATA\Favorites"`

OR

`Get-ChildItem "C:\Appsensevirtual" -Recurse -Filter "Favorites*" -Force`

Comment: @AdiGraham: Look in C:\Appsensevirtual with an explorer to confirm there is something to view. Also confirm which version of Powershell you are running (`$PsVersionTable`).

Comment: Oh god, the reason its doign nothing is we are moving the items so they are not there! Sorry Monday and all that :(

How can i mark this as answered please?

Comment: @AdiGraham: use the grey checkmark near the vote count of the answer

Comment: Also to copy rather then move I used

`Get-ChildItem "C:\Appsensevirtual" -Recurse -Filter "Favorites*" -Force | Copy-Item -Recurse -Destination "C:\OLD_XP_DATA\Favorites"`

Comment: Thanks again Matt, i appreciate all your help.